# AngularJS factory function going straight to catch block on initial execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to call a function from my dataService to return a value from my database.

The issue is, from debugging I can see when the function is first called, the .then blocks of the promise seem to be skipped over initially and it jumps straight to the catch block.

The view then loads in, with the initial value of dataService.favourites which is an empty array as opposed to the updated value that the getFavourites function returns, the function then executes the .then blocks and gets data back from the database, but at this point it's too late as the controller has already initialised with the original empty array from the factory.

node.js function to call the database...

```
app.get('/user/getFavourites', function (req, res) {

    User.find({ username: req.session.passport.user }, 'favourites', function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send("Couldn't get favourites")
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(docs);
        }
    })
        .lean();
})
```

Function in the angularJS factory...

```
      getFavourites: function () {
        $http.get('/user/getFavourites')

          .then(function (response) {
            return $http.get('/user/getFavourites')
          })

          .then(function (response) {
            this.favourites = [...response.data[0].favourites];
            return this.favourites;
          })

          .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
      }

    })
```

Controller where I call the function...

```
  dataService.getFavourites();

    console.log(dataService.favourites);
```

Lastly the view...

```
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 cocktailResultsContainer" ng-repeat="favourite in dataService.favourites">
            <button class="btn deleteFavouriteButton" ng-click="deleteFavourite()"><i
                            class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i></button>
            <a href="#!CocktailDetails" ng-click="selectedCocktail($index)">
                <h3 class="text-center cocktailHeader"><strong>{{favourite.cocktailName}}</strong></h3>
                <img ng-src="{{favourite.cocktailImage}}" alt="Cocktail image" class="cocktailImageSearchResult">
            </a>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Essentially my goal is to get the updated value of dataService.Favourites before the view loads in.

I've read through some documentation on AngularJS promises, but I feel as though I am not fully understanding the concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your goal of getting "the updated value of dataService.Favourites before the view loads in" may be possible, but not in the way you are trying to do it.

First, you need to understand that dataService.getFavourites returns 1) nothing and 2) immediately.  If you want to `console.log(dataService.favourites);` after it finishes requesting /user/getFavourite, then you need to wait for it to finish.  You do this by returning a Promise.  You are also making the request a second time for the first then block.  It should looks something like this

```js
getFavourites: function () {
  return $http.get('/user/getFavourites')

    .then(function (response) {
      this.favourites = [...response.data[0].favourites];
      return this.favourites;
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Failed to request /user/getFavourites", error);
    })
}
```

Then you can wait for it by calling `then` on the return value, which is a Promise.

```js
dataService.getFavourites()
  .then(function() {
    console.log(dataService.favourites);
  })
```

But that still is not going to get you what you want.  Calling this from the controller is not going to make Angular wait to render the component while the data is fetched. You may be able to use the $routeProvider to make Angular wait.  Checkout https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider.  Specifically, checkout the resolve property on the route param.

Another solution, which is pretty common, is to design a "loading" state for your components template - something it can render while you wait for the data to load. Then the data finishes loading, you use angular's data binding to update the template.

And another solution is to design an "empty" state, giving your component a look for when there is no data and then updating it when the data has finished loading.